# Does Uvicorn support Stats Server Mechanism?

Tags: python, fastapi, datadog, uvicorn, asgi

I am working on a FastAPI web application and using [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/) ASGI server. Now, want to configure server stats in Uvicorn but have not found a reference regarding.

Ex - As like [uWSGI Stats Server](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StatsServer.html#the-uwsgi-stats-server) provides stats -
`uwsgi --socket :3031 --stats :1717 --module welcome`

So, my question is Does Uvicorn supports the stats server mechanism? or, Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is an open issue on `uvicorn` for this. Check this comment for details https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/610#issuecomment-611987371